# Speed of LU decomposition vs traditional Ax=b

Tags: python-3.x, performance, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

Learning about LU decompositions, and the textbook I'm using claimed that once the initial matrices *L* and *U* have been computed (assuming no pivoting matrix *P* is needed), it is much faster/more efficient (aka less flops) to solve *Ly = b* and then *Ux = y* than *Ax = b* from scratch. However, when I ran it on my system with a random *A* ⊆ R^(10 x 10) matrix and *b* ⊆ R^(10 x 1), it ended up being much slower (12.49 seconds vs 6.17 seconds).

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lu
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy.linalg import solve
from timeit import timeit as duration

A, b = rand(500, 500), rand(500, 1)
P,L,U = lu(A)

t_vanilla = duration("solve(A,b)", setup="from __main__ import solve, A, b")
print(t_vanilla)
t_decomps = duration("solve(U, solve(L,b))", setup="from __main__ import solve, L, U, b")
print(t_decomps)
```

Any ideas on why this might be the case? This is my first time using the `timeit` library, so I may well have messed something up haha. I'm running this on Mac OSX, python 3.8.

Also, I noticed that `scipy.solve` was **WAY** slower (over double the time) than `numpy.solve` for some reason ... any intuition as to why?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Not only speed, but you need to compare the roundoff errors. You will find the build-in solver to reduce these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When running `solve(U, solve(L,b))`, you just give to [LAPACK gesv](https://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/tc4600/intel/2017.0.098/mkl/common/mklman_c/GUID-4CC4330E-D9A9-4923-A2CE-F60D69EDCAA8.htm) routine behind `np.linalg.solve` two distinct linear systems that it blindly solves without accounting for the triangular structure of `L` and `U`. This is done by performing respectively for each a LU factorization followed by forward, `Ly = b` , and backward, `Ux = y`, substitution. That is why your timings seem to indicate roughly twice the time as a single `solve` call.

Now according to your textbook, and more generally, the numerical efficiency that comes from already having the LU decomposition of matrix `A`, is that you can simply reuse it if you have multiple right-hand side `b` in order to avoid a costly and redundant factorization step. In order to do so, you only need to solve the two triangular systems `Ly = b` by forward substitution then `Ux = y` using backward substitution. Let me time these as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lu_factor, lu_solve, lu

A, b = np.random.rand(500, 500), np.random.rand(500, 1)
P,L,U = lu(A)
lu_A = lu_factor(A)

# LU + forward backward
%timeit np.linalg.solve(A, b)
>>> 1.4 ms ± 10.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# 2 x (LU + forward backward)
%timeit np.linalg.solve(U, np.linalg.solve(L, b))
>>> 2.39 ms ± 85.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# forward backward
%timeit lu_solve(lu_A, b)
>>> 69.8 µs ± 6.48 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

and it is indeed far more efficient if you have multiple `b` to solve for.

Note that I used [scipy.linalg.lu_factor](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu_factor.html), which stores a compact form of the LU factorization, followed by [scipy.linalg.lu_solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu_solve.html), which solves the system with the decomposition given by `lu_factor`.

Note also that reusing the LU factorization is useful when these multiple `b` are not available at the same time. On the contrary if they are readily available, you could simply make a single `solve` call with horizontally stacked `b` with equivalent performance as the solver itself will reuse the LU factorization computed for the first one for every remaining `b`.

Concerning the performances issues with scipy it's rather hard to say without more informations about numpy/scipy (`np.show_config()`).

Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: That makes sense - I didn't realize you could use ```lu_factor``` like that. I'm curious though: how is your system running so fast? If I try to solve a 500 x 500 matrix on mine, it takes minutes at a time. Do you have some special configurations or something? Thanks!!

Comment: I am just running these with python Intel MKL on Linux, nothing really special :) Your timings seem really slow indeed...

Comment: For future people: the problem is ```timeit```! If you're not using iPython, then the imported timeit function defaults to *one million runs*! You can override this by setting the default number of runs argument to something small (like 100) using ```number = 100```. Scipy is definitely still slower, however. Thank you!

Comment: I was just going to suggest you to directly use magicpython syntax within the iPython console :)